# password_verify() PHP 5.5.12 Não está funcionando

Tags: php, segurança, hash, senhas, password

Estou tendo problemas com password_verify (). Alguns dias atrás, a mesma senha e hash funcionavam perfeitamente. Hoje, password_verify retorna falso, mas eu sei que a senha está correta.

```
$senhaC = '$2y$10$15rGMwy5CEHaLrNzEEwaZ.G2.VbhumhXtcORad0cC7W6SkjuZ.XJG';
$senha  = 'tgipassword';

var_dump(password_get_info($senhaC));

if (password_verify($senha, $senhaC)) {
    echo 'Ok';
}
else {
    echo 'No Ok';
}
```

var_dump retorna:

```
array (size=3)
  'algo' => int 1
  'algoName' => string 'bcrypt' (length=6)
  'options' => 
    array (size=1)
      'cost' => int 10
```

Quando foi criada e salva no banco foi utilizando:

```
$options = [
    'cost' => 10
]; 
$senhaC = password_hash('tgipassword', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
```

Eu faço uma pesquisa no banco ele me retorna esse hash mas na verificação com a senha correta retorna falso, o estranho é que usei esta senha a uns dias atrás verificando como verdadeiro e sei que a senha não foi mudada.

Comment: Já tentou atualizar a senha? para ver?

Comment: Não configurou nenhum salto no `password_hash`?

Comment: A versão do php mudou?

Comment: Quando eu faço a função do meu software que regera a senha, eu coloco a mesma ele regera e funciona. O estranho é não estar funcionando algo que estava.

Comment: A versão do PHP não foi alterada, não configurei nenhum salt. Usei apenas aquilo descrito na pergunta, custo 10 e PASSWORD_DEFAULT.

Comment: Meu medo é um usuário tentar logar e não funcionar dizendo que a senha esta errada e a senha estiver certa.